# SQL WHERE Filtering

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns id, first_name, last_name, email, gender, department and car. I can see the numbers of cars with this:

```
SELECT car, COUNT(car)  FROM Workers GROUP BY car;
```

Now I'm trying to see the numbers of cars which are owned by only males or females. I tried this:

```
 SELECT car, COUNT(car)  FROM Workers GROUP BY car WHERE gender = 'Male';
```

but it is giving syntax error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Select gender, car, count(*) total from ... group by gender, car

Comment: What do you mean "which cars are owned only by males or females"?  Sample data and desired results would help.  Can a car have multiple owners?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Where` clause should go before `group by` clause :

```
SELECT car, COUNT(car)  
FROM Workers  
WHERE gender = 'Male' 
GROUP BY car;
```

As because you want record level filtration not after groping the records.

> I'm trying to see the numbers of cars which are owned by only males or females.

So, `where` clause should

```
WHERE gender IN ('Male', 'Female');
```

Comment: By latter, did you assume genders could go beyond those two?

Comment: @revo. . . later looked @ `cars which are owned by only males or females.` and op might have other kind data in `gender` such `null`s, etc...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do male and female in one request you can do:

```
SELECT car, gender, COUNT(car) 
FROM Workers
GROUP BY car, gender;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    SELECT gender, COUNT(car)  FROM Workers GROUP BY gender ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It Simple.

**Please Write** Where should go before `group by`

```
SELECT car, COUNT(car) FROM Workers  
WHERE gender = 'Male' GROUP BY car
```